# Prove that $G$ is a tree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph possessing the property that for every two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, there exists exactly one $u$-$v$ path. Prove that $G$ is a tree.

Comment: You need to specify your definition of tree; some authors use what you've written as the definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Definitions

Comment: Any connected graph that has no cycles.

Comment: So it's given that it's connected, you only need to show there are no cycles.

Comment: Use the existence of a path to show that it’s connected, and use the uniqueness to show that it’s acyclic. (I’m assuming that your definition of *tree* is *connected, acyclic graph*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to show the contrapositive. Namely, if $G$ is not a tree, than either there is more than one $u-v$ path, or a disconnected pair of vertices.

If $G$ is not a tree, then it is either disconnected or contains a cycle (or both). If it is disconnected, what can you say?

If $G$ contains a cycle, call it $a_0 e_0 a_1 e_1 a_2\dots e_{n-1}a_ne_n a_0$, where the $a_i$ are vertices, $e_i$ are edges, and $a_i\neq a_j$, $e_i\neq e_j$ if $i\neq j$. How could you come up with two paths between, for example, $a_0$ and $a_n$?